# Need to extract a substring from a file path string including the delimiter

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing

While executing a shell script, an input string is similar to this:

```
test1/test2/Test.jar/Test2.jar/com/test/ui/GI.class
```

How can I extract:
`test1/test2/Test.jar` [i.e. substring till first occurrence of '.jar' delimiter, inclusive], in shell script

How can I do this? I would not like to use cut and then append '.jar' at the end.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `sed` like below:

```
sed 's/\(\.jar\).*/\1/' <<<"test1/test2/Test.jar/Test2.jar/com/test/ui/GI.class"
```

Or through `awk` command:

```
awk -F'\\.jar' '{print $1".jar"}' <<<"test1/test2/Test.jar/Test2.jar/com/test/ui/GI.class"
```

The output is:

```
test1/test2/Test.jar
```

Answer (score 7):

[Besides `sed`](https://askubuntu.com/a/939827/22949), you also have the option of using [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html) for this, with the PCRE regex `^.*?\.jar`:

```bash
grep -oP '^.*?\.jar' <<<"test1/test2/Test.jar/Test2.jar/com/test/ui/GI.class"
```

This prints only the match (`-o`), uses [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) (`-P`), and matches text that:

- starts at the beginning of the line (`^`), and
- contains any character (`.`),  any number of times but matched lazily (`*?`),
- followed by a literal `.` character (`\.`) and `jar` (`jar`)

Using the [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*?` instead of the usual greedy quantifier `*` causes `grep` to match the fewest characters possible.

- Without it (and with the greedy quantifier instead), `grep` would match as many characters as possible so long as the match ended in `.jar`, which would fail to stop after the *first* `.jar` in cases where there is more than one.
- The `-P` flag is required because, of the regex dialects `grep` supports on Ubuntu, [PCRE is the one that supports laziness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3027524/1038860). ([This dialect](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcrepattern) is very similar to [the regex dialect in Perl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/perlre.1.html).)

Answer (score 6):

Since you mention shell scripting I present a simple, purely shell based solution:

```sh
s='test1/test2/Test.jar/Test2.jar/com/test/ui/GI.class'
echo "${s%%.jar*}.jar"
```

The [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) `%%` removes the *longest suffix* that matches the subsequent [glob pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) `.jar*` (as opposed to `%` which matches the shortest suffix).

Comment: `%%` is standard. The *Parameter Expansion* sections of [IEEE 1003.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), [IEEE 1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02), and [SUSv2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_006_002) all cover it as "Remove Largest Suffix Pattern." Although not all Bourne-style shells are standards-conforming, I believe `%%` is as portable as most of the other shell features we typically say are portable.

Comment: @EliahKagan: Thanks! I removed those parts of the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is tagged `bash`, here's a `bash` script with C-style loop and `${variable:beginning:offset}` parameter expansion to extract individual characters

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

substring=""
for ((i=0;i<=${#1};i++))
do
    substring="$substring""${1:$i:1}"
    if [[ "$substring" == *.jar ]]
    then
        echo "$substring"
        substring=""
    fi
done
```

This works like so in action:

```
$ ./parse_string.sh test1/test2/Test.jar/Test2.jar/com/test/ui/GI.class                                                                              
test1/test2/Test.jar
/Test2.jar
```

If we wanted to extract only the first occurrence, add `break` on line after `substring=""` inside `if` statement

Comment: Why use a C-loop? Why not just `${str//.jar*/.jar}`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster pls post that as an answer - IMHO this is by far preferable to all the sed/awk/grep/perl solutions suggested so far

Comment: @terdon because iterating over characters of the string is the first idea to which my mind gravitated for some reason; no specific reason.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I agree with steeldriver. You might want to post that as answer.

Answer (score 3):

In `python`:

```
python3 -c "print('blub/blab/Test.jar/blieb'.split('.jar')[0]+'.jar')"

> blub/blab/Test.jar
```

or:

```
python3 -c "s='blub/blab/Test.jar/blieb';print(s[:s.find('.jar')+4])"

> blub/blab/Test.jar
```

Comment: Second version is better ;)